# Extracting data attribute display name from c# class?

Tags: c#

I am able to get a simple text list of all the property names in a specified class using the following code.

```
  PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
  propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
  foreach (var item in propertyInfos)
     {
     yield return item.Name.ToString();
     }
```

But I have not been able to figure out how to get the Display Name for each field. The display name being designated with the data attribute:

```
 [Display(Name = "First Name")]
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Is there a way using reflection? Or some other way to do it programatically?

Comment: I think(know) there's a way to reflect on the attributes.  Try GetCustomAttributes()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get CustomAttribute by type in this way:

```
DisplayAttribute attribute = (DisplayAttribute)item.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute));
```

Now you can get any value of DisplayAttribute fields just using for example

```
attributes.Name
```